# Collect files from another folder

Tags: makefile, pandoc

I developed a script to convert all the markdowns files in my folder to ePub and place them in `epubs`.

Nevertheless I would like to place my files in the `markdowns` sub-folder and not in the main directory (the one where the `makefile` is).

```
.
├── epubs
│   └── blabla.epubs
├── makefile
└── markdowns
    └── blabla.pd
```

How should I modify my code?

```
MARKDOWN=$(shell find . -iname "*.pd")
EPUBS=$(MARKDOWN:.pd=.epub)

.PHONY = all clean
all: $(EPUBS)

%.epub: %.pd
        pandoc --from markdown --to epub --smart $< -o epubs/$@

clean:
        rm epubs/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to explicitly tell `make` in your pattern rule where the `.pd` prerequisites for the `.epub` targets reside:

```
MARKDOWN_DIR := markdowns
EPUB_DIR := epubs

MARKDOWNS := $(wildcard $(MARKDOWN_DIR)/*.pd)
EPUBS := $(subst $(MARKDOWN_DIR),$(EPUB_DIR),$(MARKDOWNS:.pd=.epub))

$(EPUB_DIR)/%.epub: $(MARKDOWN_DIR)/%.pd
    pandoc --from markdown --to epub --smart $< -o $@

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(EPUBS)
```

Note two minor additional changes. I replaced your shell `find` command with `make`'s `$(wildcard)` function because that is what it's for. Your `pandoc` command no longer needs `epubs/` in front of `$@` because that directory is now part of the target. And I reordered a bit according to my liking.